# Submitting form via bootstrap modal and codeigniter automatically closes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

Just started coding; using codeigniter and bootstrap. I am trying to submit a form via a simple modal with a yes or no button. However, when I click the button in the view the modal starts to open and closes immediately. The data is posting to the db but, I want the user to click the yes or no box first.

Here is my controller:

```
function skatersuccess(){
    if (!$this->ion_auth->is_admin())
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">You must be an admin to view this page</div>');
        redirect('/');
    }

    $event_id = $this->input->post('event_id');
    $user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');

    $user_data = array(
            'id'    => 'null',
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'event_id' => $event_id,
            'is_paid' => 1
        );

    $this->user_event_model->registerskater($user_data);
    redirect('/dashboard/','refresh');
    }
```

Here is my model:

```
public function registerskater($user_data) {
        $this->load->database('hockey');
        $this->db->insert('users_events', $user_data);
    }
```

Here is the mainview button code(this loads the popup modal:

```
<?php if (($e->user_registered == 1)) : ?>
  <?php $this->load->view('admin/partial/skater_cancel', $e) ?>
  <?php elseif (($e->capacity == $e->registered)): ?>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">FULL</button>
  <?php else: ?>
  <?php $this->load->view('admin/partial/skater', $e) ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

and here is the popup modal view:

```
    <form action="dashboard/skatersuccess" name="" id="login-form" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" >SIGN UP AS SKATER</button></p></td

    <!--Pop Up Dialog-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true">    </span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Signup for Game?</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

    <div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span>Are you sure you want to sign up for game?</div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer ">



    <button type="button" id="btnYES" href="#" name="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Yes</button>

    <input id="event_id" type="hidden" class="form-control" name="event_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" placeholder="event_id">
        <input id="user_id" type="hidden" class="form-control" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('user_id'); ?>" placeholder="user_id">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> No</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content --> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog --> 
    </div>


</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is beacause of  the button is in a Form that was temporarily just fetching the same page.

**Replace your button with this**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" >
    SIGN UP AS SKATER
</button>
```

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers